# How can I render an infinite 2D grid in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Ideally, what I'd like to do is draw a single quad and have GLSL handle the creation of the actual gridlines.

In my attempt so far the vertex shader:

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec4 in_position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 in_UV;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

smooth out vec3 ex_UV;
smooth out vec3 ex_originalPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_position;

    ex_UV = in_UV;
    ex_originalPosition = vec3(in_position.xyz);
}
```

The model matrix scales the quad up by some large number, like 10,000.

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

smooth in vec3 ex_UV;
smooth in vec3 ex_originalPosition;

uniform vec4 lineColor;

void main(void)
{
    if(fract(ex_UV.x / 0.001f) < 0.01f || fract(ex_UV.y / 0.001f) < 0.01f)
        color = lineColor;
    else
        color = vec4(0);
}
```

I've tried using both the Texture coords and the world space positions for this. Both result in the same affect which looks fine at some angles, but at others it starts looking horrid.

[image]

[image]

I thought maybe I could scale the alpha depending on the distance, so that my grid fades away into nothing, but the problem is that you can see in the second image, from the center of the screen, you can see that even those lines are being rendered with gaps through them (the point of the grid is to give a visual frame of reference around the origin).

Is there a simpler way to do this?

### EDIT

Screenshots as requested:

### VBO Lines with x8 Multisampled Framebuffer

[image]

### VBO Lines with x8 Multisampled Framebuffer and glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)

[image]

### I settled on

I settled on the either of the above (doesn't really matter which) and simply lowered the alpha as a function of distance from the origin. This serves my purpose though it isn't the question I asked.
[image]

Comment: I'd be interested to see the result with GL_LINES and multisampling. Could you post a screenshot as an update?

Comment: The results are essentially identical to your question. However, in the end I found that I didn't really need an infinite plane, so I've instead used a much smaller quad with a circular gradient from the origin as the alpha. It serves my purposes, though I concede your answer is correct in regards to the actual question I asked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple case of [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). Just like with polygon rendering, your fragment shader is run once per pixel. Colour is computed for a single central coordinate only and is not representative of the true colour.

[image]

1. You could create a multisample FBO and enable super-sampling. But that's expensive.
2. You could mathematically compute exactly how much line area and empty grid area is under each pixel, then colour them accordingly in the fragment shader. Given it's a uniform grid this might be in the realm of possible, but the maths might still get pretty complicated.
3. **Mipmapping** already does this for textures. Create a grid texture with just a few lines and map it so it repeats for your really large quad (make sure to set `GL_REPEAT`). Set up the correct mipmap filtering parameters for the texture and call [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml). When you call `texture2D()`/`texture()` in the fragment shader OpenGL automatically calculates which level of the mipmap to use based off the texture coordinate delta between the adjacent pixels. Finally, set up anisotropic filtering for an even more amazing looking grid.

   - https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_filter_anisotropic.txt
   - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69374/34435

   [image]

If you want a grid to be truly "infinite", I've seen some ocean renderers connect the edges of the grid to the horizon with vertical geometry. If you have enough grid before them, you could possibly get away with setting them to one flat colour - the colour at the top level of your mipmap.

---

Examples (relating to comments):

1024x2 GL_LINES drawn from a VBO
[image]

<sup>45fps (drawn 100 times for benchmark at HD res)</sup>

See the comments regarding multisampling to address GL_LINES aliasing.

A 32^2 texture mapped to a quad with mipmapping
[image]

<sup>954fps (drawn 100 times for benchmark at HD res)</sup>

```
Image img;
int w = 128;
int h = 128;
img.resize(w, h, 1);
for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
        img.data[j*w + i] = (i < w / 16 || j < h / 16 ? 255 : 0);

tex = img.upload();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, 16);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

...

//for the quick and dirty, immediate mode
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0,       0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1024,    0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1024, 1024); glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
glTexCoord2f(0,    1024); glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
glEnd();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: Textures won't guarantee gapless lines at all. Also, you're introducing a lot of unnecessary fragment processing and sampling, where in the line approach only the fragments that actually contribute to the lines would be ran. The goal was to just draw a 2D grid, and for me all of your approaches are a huge overkill.

Comment: For your first point, he specifically provides techniques for applying textures to give anti-aliased lines, followed by a comparison of naively texturing a quad vs doing it nicely. For the second point, we still need a citation for which technique is faster.

Comment: Interesting performance results. I can upvote this with clear conscience now :)

Answer (score 1):

> you can see that even those lines are being rendered with gaps through them

Oh, of course we can. And this is because you've offended CG 101. (No offense `:)`)

We use `GL_LINES` for a reason; drawing gapless lines on a computer screen isn't trivial (albeit solved). I'm talking about [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm). What you did does computations on floating-point numbers and will amount to sub-pixel lines being drawn (i.e., gaps).

My suggestion would be to scrap this GLSL code and generate the lines as regular vertices. It's going to be probably faster, and you'll get proper results.

You'll also be able to get the "fade in the distance" effect you want using regular fog computations.

Comment: ... now I feel silly. Off the top of your head do you know if a geometry shader can have triangles as an inputs and lines as an output?

Comment: @NeomerArcana If you really want to do it in shaders (you can smell it in the air :D) then I'd draw a quad and tesselate it into desired density. Again, this would make use of hardware support made upfront to take such loads. Other than that, you can trim up primitives in geometry shader, so reducing every triangle to line should be OK. Just `layout(triangles) in; layout(lines) out;`

Comment: Yep, already on it in the Geometry Shader. Got a 2D square, now I just need to sub-divide.

Comment: @NeomerArcana Just to clarify, I meant to use a Tesselation Shader; Outputting one line per one triangle in GS is fine. Outputting thousands of lines per triangle there won't be!

Comment: Drawing that many lines will be much slower than a single quad and the line primitives will still need to be antialiased. `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` might help but it still fails at line intersections.

Comment: @jozxyqk `[citation-needed]` on "will be slower". Also I don't see a requirement for "the line primitives will still need to be antialiased". Besides, there are other algorithms and approaches for drawing antialiased lines.

Comment: Fair point, I haven't benchmarked it, so I'll just say I suspect it will be quite a bit slower. The OP wants a smooth looking grid. Drawing line primitives without any antialiasing as this answer currently describes won't give them the wanted result.

Comment: Yes, ideally, they'd be nice and anti-aliased.

Comment: @NeomerArcana Then perhaps [this GPU Gem](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter22.html) can help. But then again, as I said, there's a lot to drawing lines, and I'd still stick to, well, drawing lines. The other answer by jozxyqk only really moves the problem, as it still works in "fragment space" (even if it's texture sampling).

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter much, I'm using a multisampled buffer and so far GL_LINES are rendering perfectly well and are anti-aliased.

Comment: They'll be anti-aliased because you're using multisampling, not because you're using GL_LINES.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Just saying that I'm getting the desired result without manually anti-aliasing the lines.