# 'Infinite' grid on xz plane in c++ OpenGL ES

Tags: c++, 3d, opengl-es

I want to be able to render a grid, similar to what you usually get in higher level model editors like Blender, Maya, etc. This should be a completely trivial task, but somehow I've found myself stuck for almost a whole day. Seems like there isn't a single tutorial/example out there on this particular problem in OpenGL ES.

I've seen a good example for what I'm trying to achieve using Vulkan, but I'm completely new to OpenGL, c++ and 3d graphics as a whole, so I'm finding it difficult to "translate" it to OpenGL ES.

The Vulkan example: http://asliceofrendering.com/scene%20helper/2020/01/05/InfiniteGrid/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842755/how-can-i-render-an-infinite-2d-grid-in-glsl

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the accepted answer to your thread isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Check out this article: https://ourmachinery.com/post/borderland-between-rendering-and-editor-part-1/ it is also well explained in the book _3D Graphics Rendering Cookbook_ by _Sergey Kosarevsky_ and _Viktor Latypov_, in chapter 5. To be honest, I find your linked example much easier to understand, just change the descriptor set to uniforms and enable alpha blending, it should work in OpenGL.